# Set clone starter repo to my repo

Tags: git, github

I have cloned a starter repo for angular universal, and it has all my working source code but its still named and related to the original repo.
I am not sure how to make my own repo (that I can push and pull with over different computers with github desktop)

Ive tried:

- Making a copy of the folder and trying to add that as a repo on my github
- Delete git related files and declaring it as a new repo with cmd
- Sharing it as a new repo with PHPStorm

I have had almost no experience with git and github management and im sure the answer is obvious but im going in circles at the moment

Comment: you need to make fork

Answer (score 0):

You should fork and then clone the repo. After forking the repo in github, you can rename it if you want

Once you cloned the repo to your local machine always verify the remotes to make sure the origin is pointing to your remote rather than the upstream from which you forked.

`git remote -v`

So incase if you cloned the upstream repo, this step will help to verify that. You can add upstream repo's link also if you need to get changes from that often.

```
git remote add upstream upstreamrepourl
```

And incase if you already cloned the upstream repo you have option to delete the remote origin and add with it your github remote url. In this case your git folder names should match whatever in your local and remote.

```
git remote rm origin
```

And add the origin with ur github link

```
git remote add origin yourremoteurl
```

The idea is from where ever you clone the the repo that will be your origin always that's is why verifying the remotes is a good practice after you cloned it.